# Как в Visual Studio 2013 отключить белую подсветку в файлах *.cshtml?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот так вот подсвечиваются все Razor выражения независимо нахожусь я в них или нет.

Comment: Отключить нельзя, а вот изменить цвет можно. Кажется можно через расширение [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/) попробовать отключить. Посмотрите этот ответ: [Disable Visual Studio code formatting in Razor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30668888/5275890)

Answer (score 1):

Измените соответствующую опцию в настройках Visual Studio.

В `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Text Editor`
выберите `HTML Razor Code Background`, затем установите для него нужный вам фон.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для VS2015 и VS2017 данная настройка также работает +1